# Is it possible to choose the base line of the ycomb?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to choose the base line of the `ycomb` (vertical lines)?

For example, in log scale, the default base line is at `y=1` (or `y=10^0`). But I would like to make it at `y=0` (i.e. minus infinity). The reason is that if all the values are below `y=1` the comb goes up instead of down (which is confusing).

[image: ycomb]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log]
\addplot[ycomb,mark=*] coordinates  {% #points 5
( 0, 100 )
( 1, 10 )
( 2, 1 )
( 3, 0.1 )
( 4, 0.01 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `log origin=infty` to make the `ycomb` plot start at the bottom of the plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymode=log, log origin=infty]
\addplot[ycomb,mark=*] coordinates  {% #points 5
( 0, 100 )
( 1, 10 )
( 2, 1 )
( 3, 0.1 )
( 4, 0.01 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to make comb or bar plot start from the top of the axis, you'll have to redefine an internal macro. Putting the following code chunk into your preamble will make the option `log origin=-infty` available, which makes the plots start from the top:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/log origin x/-infty/.code={\def\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@x{2}},
    /pgfplots/log origin y/-infty/.code={\def\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@y{2}},
    /pgfplots/log origin z/-infty/.code={\def\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@z{2}}
}

\def\pgfplots@prepare@ZERO@coordinates{%
    \ifpgfplots@xislinear
        \ifpgfplots@apply@datatrafo@x
            \pgfplotscoordmath{x}{parsenumber}{0}%
            \pgfplotscoordmath{x}{datascaletrafo}{\pgfmathresult}%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x=\pgfmathresult
        \else
            \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x{0}%
        \fi
        % this works in standard fixed pt math:
        \pgfplotsmathmax{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x}{\pgfplots@xmin}%
        \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotsmathmin{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x}{\pgfplots@xmax}%
        \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x=\pgfmathresult
    \else
        \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@x0%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x=\pgfplots@xmin%
        \else
            \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@x2%
                \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x=\pgfplots@xmax%
            \else
                \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x{0}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    %
    \ifpgfplots@yislinear
        \ifpgfplots@apply@datatrafo@y
            \pgfplotscoordmath{y}{parsenumber}{0}%
            \pgfplotscoordmath{y}{datascaletrafo}{\pgfmathresult}%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y=\pgfmathresult
        \else
            \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y{0}%
        \fi
        \pgfplotsmathmax{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y}{\pgfplots@ymin}%
        \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotsmathmin{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y}{\pgfplots@ymax}%
        \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y=\pgfmathresult
    \else
        \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@y0%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y=\pgfplots@ymin%
        \else
            \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@y2%
                \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y=\pgfplots@ymax%
            \else
                \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y{0}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    %
    \ifpgfplots@threedim
        \ifpgfplots@zislinear
            \ifpgfplots@apply@datatrafo@z
                \pgfplotscoordmath{z}{parsenumber}{0}%
                \pgfplotscoordmath{z}{datascaletrafo}{\pgfmathresult}%
                \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z=\pgfmathresult
            \else
                \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z{0}%
            \fi
            \pgfplotsmathmax{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z}{\pgfplots@zmin}%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z=\pgfmathresult
            \pgfplotsmathmin{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z}{\pgfplots@zmax}%
            \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z=\pgfmathresult
        \else
            \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@z0%
                \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z=\pgfplots@zmin%
            \else
                \if\pgfplots@log@origin@choice@z2%
                    \global\let\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z=\pgfplots@zmax%
                \else
                    \gdef\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z{0}%
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    %
    %
    \ifpgfplots@threedim
        \pgfplotsqpointxyz{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x}{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y}{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z}%
    \else
        \pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x}{\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y}%
    \fi
    \xdef\pgfplots@ZERO@x{\the\pgf@x}%
    \xdef\pgfplots@ZERO@y{\the\pgf@y}%
    \xdef\pgfplotspointaxisorigin{\noexpand\global\pgf@x=\pgfplots@ZERO@x\space\noexpand\global\pgf@y=\pgfplots@ZERO@y\space}%
    %
    %
    %--------------------------------------------------
    % \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/axis/zero/x}\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@x
    % \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/axis/zero/y}\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@y
    % \ifpgfplots@threedim
    %   \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/axis/zero/z}\pgfplots@logical@ZERO@z
    % \fi
    %-------------------------------------------------- 
}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Ah! in chapter 4 for the pgfplots manual. It even says: "The choice log origin=0 defines the logarithmic origin to be the natural choice log(1) = 0. This is particularly useful for ycomb plots." I would actually say that `log origin=infty` is a more natural choice, at least for log scale.

Comment: @alfC: I wouldn't say that, because the bottom of the plot is a completely arbitrary value (some argue that you really shouldn't be using comb or bar plots with logarithmic axes, because the length of the comb or bar has no meaning in such a plot)

Comment: I totally agree. The only reason I was using `ycomb` (in log scale) was to make a 3D easier to visualize and for the scale I was showing the combs where coming from above (because all the z-values where less than 1) 

By the way, can this be used to make the `comb` come from above always (e.g. `log origin=-infty`).

Comment: @alfC: That option doesn't exist yet, but you can easily add that functionality. I've edited my answer to show how.